# Script to periodically move files older than x to different drive?

Tags: windows-7

Background: My media center PC records TV programs to an external Drobo unit. Recording and watching two HD programs pushes the limit of the USB throughput though and playback stutters if there's any additional hard disk activity. Since FW800 seems to be impossible to get working reliably under Windows 7, I'm looking into recording TV unto the internal hard disk and moving the files periodically onto the Drobo. Which brings me to my question:

Can somebody give me a script or other method that will move files created more than a day ago and/or which aren't currently in use to a different drive/folder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows 7 include a command line utility named [robocopy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy) for bulk file operations. You need to create a `.cmd` file using something like this:

```
robocopy "c:\Internal folder" "e:\External folder" /S /MOV /MINAGE:1 /IS /R:1 /W:1
```

and then create a scheduled task that runs that file every few hours.

Comment: @deceze A detail I forgot to mention, the script won't delete files that are in use since that is blocked by Windows itself, but could copy the used files to the external folder (if they are opened with shared access), so for a brief time you can have two copies of the same file. The internal copy will be deleted by the next run of the script as soon as it stops being used.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`find`](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/findutils.htm) to find them and [`move`](http://www.computerhope.com/movehlp.htm) to move them.

Answer (score 0):

"You can try setting it as a scheduled task

Start>all programs>accessories>system tools>scheduled tasks"

http://www.computing.net/answers/windows-xp/how-do-i-auto-run-batch-file-every-60-minute/179011.html